# Ubuntu 18.10 - how to install a specific version of gcc

Tags: apt, 18.10, gcc, vmware-workstation

Disclaimer: I have searched and read similar posts and they do not answer my question.  Moving this post from SO where it was a skosh off topic.

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 and need to install gcc 8.2.0 to build kernel modules.  apt-get wants to install 8.3 which doesn't match how my kernel was built.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc:8.2.0
```

but I get the error message that the package could not be found.

I tried going the route of installing 8.3 and then building 8.2.0 and installing it into /usr/local/bin.  It worked for a few modules but when I tried building kernel modules for VMWare it complained that the package was not installed correctly.  I am a CentOS guy so a little out of my element on debian based distros.

I located gcc 8.2.0 [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gcc) as part of the core for Cosmic (18.10) and downloaded it.  apt still complained when I tried to install it, saying it needed to install 8.3.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=4:8.2.0-1ubuntu1 --no-upgrade
```

and it still wants to install 8.3.  There must be a way to do this but I cannot figure out how.

Output of "apt policy":

```
sudo apt policy gcc gcc-8

apt policy gcc gcc-8
gcc:
  Installed: 4:8.3.0-1ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 4:8.3.0-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 4:8.3.0-1ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:8.2.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
gcc-8:
  Installed: 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10
  Candidate: 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10
  Version table:
 *** 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.2.0-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

What does the output mean?  I see 8.2 listed in the available packages.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install gcc-8`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy gcc gcc-8`

Comment: Jim sudo apt install gcc-8" installs 8.3 or, in this case, tries to and finds it already installed.

Comment: @steeldriver  Done!

Comment: @Notamachine Have you tried `=` instead of `:` and using actual version string, i.e. `sudo apt-get install gcc=8.2.0-7ubuntu1`?

Comment: @Kulfy  I get farther.  It complains about unmet dependencies.  I listed cpp-8, gcc-8-base, libgcc-8-dev on the command line but then it spewed a large list of dependencies which were unmet.

Comment: @Kulfy  I ran this clever code and it still installed 8.3.  `sudo apt-cache depends gcc-8=8.2.0-7ubuntu1 | grep 'Depends:' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y`

Comment: Thank you to all who prompted for questions and thoughts.  I am going to move to another distro unless I can get this answered in the next day or two.